# How to Add Chart Title in WPF LiveCharts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I have gone through the [tutorials and examples](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basics) in LiveChart's documentation (for WPF) but could not find any clue on how to add chart titles and subtitles. The ones available are axis title like the code below:

How can I add a title and subtitle to the WPF LiveChart (preferably in XAML)?

Axis Title:

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
     <lvc:Axis Title="X-Axis Title"> </lvc:Axis>
 </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
 <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
      <lvc:Axis Title="Y-Axis Title" ></lvc:Axis>
 </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
```

Chart Title: ???

```
<lvc:CartesianChart LegendLocation="Right" >
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Comment: I would use two labels along with the chart in a stackpanel

Comment: I thought of that @SirRufo, but I didn't want to go that route. I was hoping there's a property in the LiveCharts I would have to set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such property. You can use labels to achieve the same thing by placing them inside of a StackPanel with your chart.